# Placing tablesorter JS at the foot of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using mottie's fork
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/
BUT does anyone know why placing the JS at the bottom of the page to help speed up the loading, doesnt work for this JS?

```
<script src="DOMAIN/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({
    sortList : [[3,1]], // initial sort columns (2nd and 3rd)
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort"
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Speed up loading or initializing? Both depend on the size of the table.

If there are 1000+ rows, the page itself will be large and loading will take time.

Initializing 1000+ rows will also take some time as tablesorter needs to process each cell & cache the data to optimize sorting.

Either way, the best solution is to only show users a subset of data by using the pager with ajax.

Comment: this is just a testing table, i just want to place the 30+kb JS at the bottom at the footer and call initialisation there....it doesnt like it....Google speed test like to move things down the bottom

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: <script src="DOMAIN/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
    sortList : [[3,1]], // initial sort columns (2nd and 3rd)
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort"
  });
});
</script>

Comment: Ok, so how many rows... 30k sounds like it should be about 50? Is it tablesorter that is slow or is there some other script? Add a `debug:true` option to tablesorter and see where it might be hanging. Otherwise use the DevTools in your browser check the timeline or profiles on the page.

Comment: NO NO NO about 5 rows; jquery.tablesorter.min.js is 37KB

Comment: So whats the answer? does the JS file have to be called and initialised before the element? Thats weird because really it only rearranging whats already loaded i assume?

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing a demo and figuring out why the page is loading/initializing slowly. If that code is at the bottom of the page, and the table has been fully rendered, then there is no need to wrap the code in a document ready function (`$(function(){ ... });`). Maybe try commenting out the `sortList` and see if you notice any change in initialization. If not, remove all of that code and see if there is any difference.

Comment: it doesnt RUN at all at the bottom of the page